# Changes in Android 11, no longer able to provide mock location

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, location

I have an app that provides mock locations, works fine up to Android 10, however on Android 11 it no longer works, I just get the error "Error while pushing mock location gps provider is not a test provider"
I searched the docs but I can't find any info on what may be causing the error.
Is this a permission issue? I am not sure what changed, the APK works fine on Android 10 and less but not 11.

Comment: Are you providing a mock location provider for other apps to consume, or one that is being consumed within your own app via `AddTestProvider` ?

Comment: It is for other apps to consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, when adding the provider to the location manager, I could no longer specify a power of 'no requirement' or an accuracy of 'high'.
I had to specify low power and medium accuracy. I understand the power one but not sure why accuracy high would not be allowed for android 11.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of study I found below helpful solution helpful. Actually error itself stated that

> powerRequirement is out of range of [1, 3] (too low)

While adding your test provider you can assign power requirements from 0 to 1.

```
locationManager.addTestProvider(this._provider, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, **1**, 1);
```